# Bounding an integral of a function with its Fourier coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable on $L^{1}([0,2\pi])$, with Fourier coefficients $\hat{f} \in l^1(\mathbb{Z})$. Is the following manipulation valid?

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(x)|^4 \ \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\left| \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(n)e^{inx}\right|^4 \ \mathrm{d}x \leqslant \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left( \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} | \hat{f}(n) | \right)^4 \ \mathrm{d}x = 2\pi \left( \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{f}(n)| \right)^4$$

Is this valid, or is it also necessary that $f \in L^{4}([0,2\pi])$? Are there additional conditions that $f$ must satisfy for this to hold that I haven't mentioned? I feel as though I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: You need $f \in L^4$.

Comment: @copper.hat If the Fourier coefficients are in $l^1$, then $f$ is continuous, hence belongs to $L$-everything.

Comment: @zhw.: I missed the $l_1$ part.

Comment: I think you want $[a,b]= [0,2\pi].$

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Could you explain why the $l^1$-summability of the Fourier coefficients imply continuity of $f$, and why this means $f \in L^{p}$ for all $p \geqslant 1$? (Does it also imply the same for $p \in (0,1)$, by the way?)

Comment: It takes a bit of work, but if the coefficients are in $l^1$ then the partial sums converge to a continuous function $\tilde{f}$ which equals $f$ ae.

Comment: @copper.hat So we can bound $f$ by $\sum {|\hat{f}|}$ -- does this imply that $f$ is essentially bounded because all bounded functions are essentially bounded? I guess this means that $f \in L^{\infty}$ -- why does this imply that $f \in L^4$?

Comment: $L^\infty[a,b] \subset L^p[a,b]$

Comment: Does that also apply for $p \in (0,1)$?

Comment: If $|f(x)| \le M$ for ae. $x$, then $|f(x)|^p \le M^p $ for ae. $x$. But how is that relevant to the question?

Comment: I see. I chose 4 as it was an arbitrary positive integer, but I wanted to know if it were true for all positive $p$.